# WebDriverWait does not ignore exceptions

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using the most current Chrome and Webdriver 2.33 and am having some issues with `IgnoreExceptionTypes`. In the below code webdriver will wait like I expect it too but it will not actually ignore the exceptions:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8));
wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(
    typeof(WebDriverTimeoutException),
    typeof(NoSuchElementException)
);  
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(firstResultX)));
```

The code is in a try/catch, I tried moving it outside of the try/catch and received the same issue. I am not sure where to go from here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/5096/5773 ... perhaps this will be helpful for you

Comment: Thanks for the link. I checked it out and it seems that person was having the same issue that I am and his issue was unresolved. To reiterate the problem is that despite providing IgnoreExceptionTypes of the correct type my automation will still raise the errors I told it to ignore.

Comment: I just ended up putting a try catch around the wait.Until call. Same thing here, IgnoreExceptionTypes appears to do nothing, or at least not what I expect it to do.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, that is what I ended up doing. I was just hoping to find a "good" way to do it.

Comment: I usually use the .ignore method in FluentWait intead of using WebDriverWait. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FluentWaits.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(getDriverInstance())
                .withTimeout(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(sleepMilliSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

wait.until(<Your expected condition clause.>);
```

Let me know if this does not solves your problem.

Comment: Good solution for Java but not for C# :)

Answer (score 0):

For C# different waits are -

```
      ` //Implicit Wait - Once set it remains till the life of the session
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        //Explicit Wait - Polling interval is 250ms
        //using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI; 
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        //this wait utility ignores no such element errors by default
        IWebElement webElement = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.Id("value")));

        //Fluent wait - Polling interval is set by us
        WebDriverWait fluentWait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
        {
            PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        };
        fluentWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(AccessViolationException), typeof(NoSuchElementException));
        IWebElement element = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.Id("value")));`
```