# What does 'Dead Store in WebDriverWait' mean?

Tags: java, selenium

I used this line within Selenium to ignore any `NotFoundException`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wd, 60);
```

Firebug displays a warning (Dead Store in WebDriverWait) for this line of code within its console. In the [documentation of `WebDriverWait`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) there is no other possibility to use this class to avoid this warning.

Did I misunderstand the usage of the `WebDriverWait`, or how can I avoid this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it means you are not using the variable `wait` afterwards. I came to that conclusion by having a look at the following commit:

https://github.com/operasoftware/operaprestodriver/commit/2ebc773973371b92fd3fde9e9336c8a75a454af8

There the variable assignment was just removed.

There are also other questions on Stack Overflow like [WebDriverWait does not ignore exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18361362/432681) or [WebDriverWait + search for an item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23418004/432681), which show the usage of `WebDriverWait`.

So I think you just need to write this instead:

```
new WebDriverWait(wd, 60);
```

Or, if you want to react to some specific event (here the element text "xyz" within the element with ID "test"), you can write something like this:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)).until(ExpectedConditions.
    textToBePresentInElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='test']"), "xyz"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right that the problem is, that i dont uses `wait` again. But this is my problem. The `WebDriverWait`is a single line - how can i avoid that i get a warning for this "correct" line?

Comment: I guess you need to just leave out the assignment. I added examples in my answer.